# Entering Y for Yes and N for No in shell Script

Tags: shell

I have a Shell script in ksh where after inputs are entered the script asks to enter Y for Yes and N for No in order to check for inputs and proceed. Below is that part of the script:

```
echo ""

YN=""
while [ "x$YN" != "xn" -a "x$YN" != "xN" -a "x$YN" != "xy" -a "x$YN" != "xY" ]; do
   echo -n "Please confirm (y/n): "
   read YN
done

if [ "x$YN" = "xn" -o "x$YN" = "xN" ]; then
   exit 0
fi
```

I am not able to understand

```
while [ "x$YN" != "xn" -a "x$YN" != "xN" -a "x$YN" != "xy" -a "x$YN" != "xY" ];
```

Could yoy kindly help me in this regard..

Comment: The code could have been precise and more readable by just changing the case of the variable to either lower or upper before checking it in the `if` .

Answer (score 1):

Actually this should be written as:

```
while [ "$YN" != "n" -a "$YN" != "N" -a "$YN" != "y" -a "$YN" != "Y" ];
```

but with some shells this would result in error if the variable `$YN` is empty. So the safe way to make the comparison work is to append a dummy character inside double quotes on both sides of the comparison (so that they cancel out each other) like:

```
while [ "x$YN" != "xn" -a "x$YN" != "xN" -a "x$YN" != "xy" -a "x$YN" != "xY" ];
```

which would not break even when `$YN` is empty.

Comment: Got It.. Thanks a lot for the answer..was wondering what "x" is doing in this case.. had some tough time with it before..